# How to fix error "could not find class 'com.github.OrangeGangsters.circularbarpager.library.CircularBar'

Tags: android

I'm trying to get [Daniel Waldron's CircularBarPager](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/CircularBarPager) working with Android Studio but unfortunately it won't work.

```
error：E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.github.OrangeGangsters.circularbarpager.library.CircularBar', referenced from method com.github.OrangeGangsters.circularbarpager.library.CircularBarPager.initializeView
```

[image: This is image]

Comment: add this to your build.gradle file:

  
   `compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:library:1.3.4@aar'`

Answer (score 2):

> Error: Could not find comes when you are trying to run your Java
>   program using java command with the class is not able to find the
>   class.

You need to follow **CircularBarPager Instructions** .

Just add this to your **`build.gradle`** file

```
compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:library:1.3.4@aar'
```

**Example**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:library:1.3.4@aar'
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`** Your Project .Hope it will works .

Comment: Although a long time has passed, but still very grateful